# How to output certain query results of Apache IoTDB to analyzing data files in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Are there any ways that support directly outputting the results of SQL statement queries to files from Apache IoTDB? If there are hundreds or thousands of rows of results that are inconvenient to view in the cli tool of IoTDB, and I want to output them to a file, then use excel or other tools to analyze them, how should I do that in IoTDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache IoTDB can support tool to export the data result you queried to csv files.
The syntax for this `export-csv.sh` tool is `tools\export-csv.bat -h <ip> -p <port> -u <username> -pw <password> -td <directory> [-tf <time-format> -datatype <true/false> -q <query command> -s <sql file> -linesPerFile <int>]`.